# ng2-bootstrap progressbar not working

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am using the ng2-bootstrap progress bar component in a Angular 2 app built with angular-cli. As suggested by the ng2-bootstrap team I have declared and used the progress bar component as shown below:

```
import { AlertModule, AccordionModule, ModalModule, ProgressbarModule  } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { ThreedViewerComponent} from './threed-viewer/threed-viewer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ThreedViewerComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    ...        
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    AccordionModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    ProgressbarModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  public customClass: string = 'customClass';
  public isFirstOpen: boolean = true;
}
```

the following is my HTML:

```
<progressbar [max]="max" [value]="dynamic">
    <span style="color:white; white-space:nowrap;">{{dynamic}} / {{max}}</span>
</progressbar>
```

and finally my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: ...  
  templateUrl: ...
})
export class myComponent{
  public max: number = 200;
  public showWarning: boolean;
  public dynamic: number;
  public type: string;

  ...
}
```

when I serve the app, theprogress bar generates following error but all other ng2-bootstrap components work fine:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
>   'max' since it isn't a known property of 'progressbar'. ("
>
> ```
>       <progressbar [ERROR ->][max]="max" [value]="dynamic">
>         <span style="color:white; white-space:nowrap;">{{dynamic}"): ThreedViewerComponent@85:23 Can't
> ```
>
> bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'progressbar'. ("
>
> ```
>       <progressbar [max]="max" [ERROR ->][value]="dynamic">
>         <span style="color:white; white-space:nowrap;">{{dynamic}} / {{max}}<"): ThreedViewerComponent@85:35 'progressbar' is not a known
> ```
>
> element:
>   1. If 'progressbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'progressbar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("
>
> ```
>       [ERROR ->]<progressbar [max]="max" [value]="dynamic">
>         <span style="color:white; white-space:nowrap"): ThreedViewerComponent@85:10 'progressbar' is not a known element:
> ```
>
> 1. If 'progressbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'progressbar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("          
>               [ERROR ->]
>               
>                   © 2017 "): ThreedViewerComponent@91:12 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: SyntaxError
>   {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
>   'max' since it isn't a known property of 'progressbar'. …,
>   _nativeError: ZoneAwareError, __zone_symbol__currentTask: ZoneTask, __zone_symbol__stack: "Error: Template parse errors:↵Can't bind to 'max' …ttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3011:35)",
>   __zone_symbol__message: "Template parse errors:↵Can't bind to 'max' since i…     © 2017 ↵"): ThreedViewerComponent@91:12"} Error:
>   Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'max' since it isn't a known
>   property of 'progressbar'. ("
>
> ```
>       <progressbar [ERROR ->][max]="max" [value]="dynamic">
>         <span style="color:white; white-space:nowrap;">{{dynamic}"): ThreedViewerComponent@85:23 Can't
> ```
>
> bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'progressbar'. ("
>
> ```
>       <progressbar [max]="max" [ERROR ->][value]="dynamic">
>         <span style="color:white; white-space:nowrap;">{{dynamic}} / {{max}}<"): ThreedViewerComponent@85:35 'progressbar' is not a known
> ```
>
> element:
>   1. If 'progressbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'progressbar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("
>
> ```
>       [ERROR ->]<progressbar [max]="max" [value]="dynamic">
>         <span style="color:white; white-space:nowrap"): ThreedViewerComponent@85:10 'progressbar' is not a known element:
> ```
>
> 1. If 'progressbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'progressbar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("          
>               [ERROR ->]
>               
>                   © 2017 "): ThreedViewerComponent@91:12
>       at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3457:33)
>       at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:86968:16)
>       at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:10223:16)
>       at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:22316:19)
>       at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:54413:68)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:54296:62
>       at Set.forEach (native)
>       at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:54296:19)
>       at createResult (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:54178:19)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.807.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2799:26)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.807.Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2591:43)
>       at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3178:57
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.807.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2832:31)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.807.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2631:47)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3011:35)

Can you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will you please change your import to this , and try again :

```
imports: [
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    AccordionModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    ProgressbarModule.forRoot(),
    ...        
  ],
```

Load all bootstrap module first `(AlertModule, AccordionModule, ModalModule, ProgressbarModule)` and then other modules.

Comment: Great , and will you please accept my answer also ?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The AlertModule is not working, the rest, yes. Why? :( I have it imported in app.module. Is there a limitation of where to put the label?

Comment: `import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
  ],
[..]`

And in my component:
`<ngx-alert>warning message</ngx-alert>`

Comment: Is it possible to create demo on stackblitz?

Comment: @ShilNevado , check `app.module.ts` `import` , here is working example , https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-bootstrap-alert

Comment: @VivekDoshi Yes, that works because it doesn't use loadChildreen. I noticed it has that problem if you put the alert inside a children module. I have just written an issue in github, seems it's not my code problem, as I can import BsDropdownModule in the same way without problems for example.

Comment: @ShilNevado, its your code problem dude , example was not even working that's why I removed the children component , i'd suggest to post a question for this that way you will get more help.

Comment: Yes, I know it was not working, for that reason I linked the stackblitz. There is a Template error. But no problem, I have just posted an issue in github as the same code with the other component from the same library doesn't have this problem. Maybe it's not possible to import alert in a child component. But if it is, it's not specified in documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163876/discussion-between-vivek-doshi-and-shil-nevado).